# How to optimize Median Filter with OpenMP (C)?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote a program that has two versions of a median filter implemented using OpenCV in C, one is sequential and the other is parallelized with OpenMP. My problem lies in that the OpenMP version seems to be running slower than my sequential one, **no matter the chunk size or the number of threads**.

Any ideas/advice is very much welcomed!

**Here is my sequential code**:

```
void medianFilter (const IplImage* img){
  IplImage* output = cvCloneImage(img);
  int rows, cols, step;
  uchar *data;

  rows = output->height;
  cols = output->width;
  step = output->widthStep;
  data = (uchar *)output->imageData;

  if(!data)
  { return; }

  //create a sliding window of size 9
  int window[9];

  for(int y = 1; y < rows - 1; y++){
      for(int x = 1; x < cols - 1; x++){

          // Pick up window element
          window[0] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x - 1)];
          window[1] = data[y * step + (x - 1)];
          window[2] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x - 1)];
          window[3] = data[(y - 1) * step + x];
          window[4] = data[y * step + x];
          window[5] = data[(y + 1) * step + x];
          window[6] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x + 1)];
          window[7] = data[y * step + (x + 1)];
          window[8] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x + 1)];

          // Sort the window to find median
          insertionSort(window);

          // Assign the median to centered element of the matrix
          data[y * step + x] = window[4];
      }
  }

  cvNamedWindow("Post-filter", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvShowImage("Post-filter", output);
  cvReleaseImage(&output);
  }
```

**Here is my parallelized code**:

```
  void omp_medianFilter (const IplImage* img){
  IplImage* output = cvCloneImage(img);
  int rows, cols, step, nthreads;
  uchar *data;

  rows = output->height;
  cols = output->width;
  step = output->widthStep;
  data = (uchar *)output->imageData;

  if(!data)
  { return; }

  // Create a sliding window of size 9
  int window[9], x, y;

  // Set the number of threads to use
  omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

  // Parallel code segment. Window, x and y are private variables for each thread
  #pragma omp parallel private(window, x, y)
  {
    //if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
      //nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      //printf("Numer of threads running: %d \n", nthreads);
    //}

    // Parallel for loop with dynamic scheduling and collapsing nested loops
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, CHUNK) collapse(2)
      for(y = 1; y < rows - 1; y++){
          for(x = 1; x < cols - 1; x++){

              // Pick up 3x3 window elements
              window[0] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x - 1)];
              window[1] = data[y * step + (x - 1)];
              window[2] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x - 1)];
              window[3] = data[(y - 1) * step + x];
              window[4] = data[y * step + x];
              window[5] = data[(y + 1) * step + x];
              window[6] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x + 1)];
              window[7] = data[y * step + (x + 1)];
              window[8] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x + 1)];

              // Sort the window to find median
              insertionSort(window);

              // Assign the median to centered element of the matrix
              data[y * step + x] = window[4];
          }
      }
    }

  cvNamedWindow("Post-filter (OMP)", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvShowImage("Post-filter (OMP)", output);
  cvReleaseImage(&output);
  }
```

**Full Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 8
#define CHUNK 15000

//Function to measure time
double get_walltime() {   
  struct timeval tp; gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
  return (double) (tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec*1e-6);
}

//Sort the window elements using insertion sort
void insertionSort(int window[])
{
    int temp, i , j;

        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            temp = window[i];
            for(j = i-1; j >= 0 && temp < window[j]; j--){
            window[j+1] = window[j];
        }
        window[j+1] = temp;
    }
}

void medianFilter (const IplImage* img){
      IplImage* output = cvCloneImage(img);
      int rows, cols, step;
      uchar *data;

      rows = output->height;
      cols = output->width;
      step = output->widthStep;
      data = (uchar *)output->imageData;

      if(!data)
      { return; }

      //create a sliding window of size 9
      int window[9];

      for(int y = 1; y < rows - 1; y++){
          for(int x = 1; x < cols - 1; x++){

              // Pick up window element
              window[0] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x - 1)];
              window[1] = data[y * step + (x - 1)];
              window[2] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x - 1)];
              window[3] = data[(y - 1) * step + x];
              window[4] = data[y * step + x];
              window[5] = data[(y + 1) * step + x];
              window[6] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x + 1)];
              window[7] = data[y * step + (x + 1)];
              window[8] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x + 1)];

              // Sort the window to find median
              insertionSort(window);

              // Assign the median to centered element of the matrix
              data[y * step + x] = window[4];
          }
      }

      cvNamedWindow("Post-filter", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
      cvShowImage("Post-filter", output);
      cvReleaseImage(&output);
    }

// Parallelized implementation of median filter
void omp_medianFilter (const IplImage* img){
      IplImage* output = cvCloneImage(img);
      int rows, cols, step, nthreads;
      uchar *data;

      rows = output->height;
      cols = output->width;
      step = output->widthStep;
      data = (uchar *)output->imageData;

      if(!data)
      { return; }

      // Create a sliding window of size 9
      int window[9], x, y, j, k, min;

      // Set the number of threads to use
      omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

      // Parallel code segment. Window, x and y are private variables for each thread
      #pragma omp parallel private(window, x, y, j, k, min)
      {
        //if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
          //nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
          //printf("Numer of threads running: %d \n", nthreads);
        //}

        // Parallel for loop with dynamic scheduling and collapsing nested loops
        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, CHUNK) collapse(2)
          for(y = 1; y < rows - 1; y++){
              for(x = 1; x < cols - 1; x++){

                  // Pick up 3x3 window elements
                  window[0] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x - 1)];
                  window[1] = data[y * step + (x - 1)];
                  window[2] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x - 1)];
                  window[3] = data[(y - 1) * step + x];
                  window[4] = data[y * step + x];
                  window[5] = data[(y + 1) * step + x];
                  window[6] = data[(y - 1) * step + (x + 1)];
                  window[7] = data[y * step + (x + 1)];
                  window[8] = data[(y + 1) * step + (x + 1)];

                  // Sort the window to find median
                  //insertionSort(window);
                  for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
                  {
                     //   Find position of minimum element
                     int min = j;
                     for (int l = j + 1; l < 9; ++l)
                       if (window[l] < window[min])
                          min = l;
                     //   Put found minimum element in its place
                     const int temp = window[j];
                     window[j] = window[min];
                     window[min] = temp;
                  }


                  // Assign the median to centered element of the matrix
                  data[y * step + x] = window[4];
              }
          }
        }

      cvNamedWindow("Post-filter (OMP)", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
      cvShowImage("Post-filter (OMP)", output);
      cvReleaseImage(&output);
      }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  IplImage* src;
  double time1, time2;

  if(argc<2){
    printf("Usage: main <image-file-name>\n\7");
    exit(0);
  }

  // Load a source image
  src = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  cvNamedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvShowImage("Original", src);

  /*time1 = get_walltime();
  medianFilter(src);
  time2 = get_walltime();
  printf("Sequential Code Performance: %fs\n", time2 - time1);*/

  time1 = get_walltime();
  omp_medianFilter(src);
  time2 = get_walltime();
  printf("Parallel Code Performance: %fs\n", time2 - time1);

  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&src);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: At the moment you change your input image before all values are calculated. Therefore your median filter is not implemented correctly. You should create a new image and assign the resulting values there.

Comment: Please provide specific performance observations and information about your system. Also include the image you used so that we can reproduce your results. You probably want to measaure the median loop separately from the pre/post-processing within the `medianFilter `functions.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` loop scheduling instead of the default? What's the performance of the default?

Comment: You are seeing the result of data races. Don't write into your input data (because it causes wrong filter results, but also because of the data races), and don't use `schedule(dynamic, CHUNK)`, let the compiler schedule for you. Also note that a partial sort is sufficient: you only need to find element #4, you don't need all the other elements sorted. Also, don't display your image in the code that does timing!

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**:

I did apply much of the advice given, and I did see performance improvemets, but the things mentioned weren't the problem.

Turns out it was something pretty stupid. I was running this on a VM with Ubuntu 16.04, and I had accidentally forgotten to increase the number of cores, therefore it was only using 1, which might as well mean it wasn't parallelized at all.

Comment: The code is still incorrect as per Cris Luengo's comment.